# Exporting Images in JAR File

Tags: java, swing, jframe, embedded-resource, illegalargumentexception

I have the Problem my Java Application gives me an error if I build it to a JAR File and Run it. But if I run it in IntelliJ itself everything is fine.

I also tried to use directly the URL but I think the URL is the Problem and creating an ImageIcon with a Path also doesn't work

Code:

```
BufferedImage apple_url = null;
BufferedImage head_url = null;
BufferedImage tail_url = null;
try {
    apple_url = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("Assets\\apple.png"));
    head_url = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("Assets\\head.png"));
    tail_url = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("Assets\\tail.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
ImageIcon icon_apple = new ImageIcon(apple_url);
ImageIcon icon_head = new ImageIcon(head_url);
ImageIcon icon_tail = new ImageIcon(tail_url);
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
        at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1400)
        at de.TheRealJan.Snake.Game.<init>(Game.java:45)
        at de.TheRealJan.Snake.Snake.<init>(Snake.java:8)
        at de.TheRealJan.Snake.Snake$1.run(Snake.java:21)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

The error says line 45 is the Problem.

Line 45 is the line :

```
apple_url = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("Assets\\apple.png"));`
```

Comment: `"Assets\\apple.png"` This might be a problem.  I'm pretty sure that Jar files use forward slash as a separator.

Comment: Yes that fixed it! Thank you very much!